# non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers

Tags: c, algorithm, int

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
￼
int a = 100; int b = 2;  int result;
result = a- b;
printf("%i\n",result);
return 0;
}
```

I have been running this code for the past hour, but it won't run. It says that "non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers". I need some insight into what that means and how to fix it. I would appreciate the help for I have been toiling over this for quite a while now.

Comment: "I have been running this code for the past hour, but it won't run" - this is like saying that "I have been reading this book for the past hour despite that I can't read". It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm sorry let me make it more specific.

Comment: Rewrite it from scratch in a new source file. Try looking at it with "vi -b".

Answer (score 9):

You have a `￼` character in your code, which you can see in your code sample above. This is preventing your code from compiling. Remove it.

Comment: Thanks, but where is it

Comment: Right before `int a = 100` and after the `{`. With your editor, go to the beginning of the `int a = 100` line, and press backspace until you reach the `{`.

Comment: Thanks for being helpful!

Comment: Quick note: it's possible that your text editor is not able to display the special character.  This would prevent you from being able to remove it.  If this is the case, consider using a different text editor.  Depending on your environment, there are a number of great alternatives: Notepad++, Eclipse, vim, emacs, etc.

Comment: @rustushki Even if an editor cannot display the special character, pressing backspace usually removes it regardless, although it might seem like pressing backspace did nothing.

Comment: Just FYI, [here's what your answer looks like to me on Chrome](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WqB8P.png). (Firefox does show the character, as a tiny dashed box with the letters "OBJ" inside it.)

Comment: Ahh I didn't realize Chrome rendered the character different, thanks.